# Implications of manually adding a user to the staff group

Tags: 16.04, permissions, users, groups

This came up as a permission issue on Ubuntu 16.04. I was unable to remove some R libraries installed in `/usr/local/lib/R/site-library`. It turned out that I did not have permission. The directory was owned by `root` and the group was `staff`.

I temporarily resolved the permission issue by manually adding my user to the `staff` group.

```
sudo usermod -a -G staff myusername    

# *see blockquote before using this!*
```

That allows me to remove the libraries from IDE.

However, when I tried to look up more information on staff group and was not able to find any definite material on the topic. Not even what the group was primarily intended for. I could only guess it is used to give similar 'enhanced' access to users on certain directories.

Are there any implications of manually adding a user to the staff group?

As an aside, is there any command to know the system-wide permissions for a group? For instance, what all are the directories for which group staff will have write permission?

Thanks.

> Edit: I must add here that using `adduser` instead of `usermod` is a much more sensible option for this operation [please see the comment below]
>
> `sudo adduser myusername staff`

Comment: For the last question, `sudo find / -type d -group staff -perm -g=w` (not counting permissions set by ACLs)

Comment: Also, there might be some information in `/usr/share/doc/base-passwd/users-and-groups.txt.gz`, but I don't an Ubuntu system on hand to check. And it's easier to use `adduser` for adding to a group: `sudo adduser myusername staff`, less chances of screwing up if you forget `-a`.

Comment: @muru. Thanks. That  pointed me in the right direction. I hqven't extracetd   that gzip file  yet, but the html file in that dir --  `/usr/share/doc/base-passwd/users-and-groups.html` has much of the information  I was looking for.  If noone else chips in with anything significantly informative,   I'd be happy to accept it as  an answer.  That might need some embellishment for sake of  future readers though, I reckon.

Comment: As for `find`, I'd already done that and dumped to a log. Will need some parsing and pruning to make sense of it.  Was wondering if there was a utility specifically for that.  Setting `-maxdepth 2` shows whole of `/local/` is owned by staff.

Comment: Ah, it might be better if you wrote the answer, since you have the information on hand. :)

Comment: ok. I guess I better follow that :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, as nudged by [@muru](https://askubuntu.com/users/158442/muru), I'm posting an answer to my own question, to the extent I can. The file `file:///usr/share/doc/base-passwd/users-and-groups.html` includes detailed information on groups and permissions. A mirror of this page can be found here: [Users and Groups](http://www.phy.ntnu.edu.tw/demolab/html.php?html=doc/base-passwd/users-and-groups)

Accordingly:

> #### staff
>
> Allows users to add local modifications to the system (`/usr/local`, `/home`) without needing root privileges. Compare with group `adm`, which is more related to monitoring/security.
>
> Note that the ability to modify `/usr/local` is effectively equivalent to root access (since `/usr/local` is intentionally on search paths ahead of `/usr`), and so you should only add trusted users to this group. Be careful in environments using NFS since acquiring another non-root user's privileges is often easier in such environments.

Of course adm is already in my `groups` so I can do `dmesg`. But I had to manually add myself to `staff`

Logging a list of directories owned by staff shows that all these belong to one of these:

```
sudo find / -maxdepth 8 -type d -group staff -perm -g=w >>stafflog.txt

/var/local
/usr/local/lib
/usr/local/share
```

No wonder the membership of staff gives me write access to my shared programming language libraries.

checking permission for one of these:

```
ls -al /var/local

drwxrwsr-x  2 root staff 4096 Apr 11  2014 .
drwxr-xr-x 16 root root  4096 Aug  3 15:55 ..
```

So apparently the staff trick  is performed by the system by setting the directories' s bit (`setguid`). , so that whichever user or process creates the files in that directory, the file always runs with the permissions shared across the staff group.  [See here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/816-4883/secfile-69/index.html)

However I still wonder whether I can safely keep myself in this group. To my mind it should be pretty safe given this is a laptop which will at worst be accessed over a trusted LAN, via smb or ssh. The words 'effectively equivalent to root access' scare me. Any thoughts on this are welcome.

Comment: In doubt you can remove yourself from the staff-group. `sudo deluser username staff`. You don't need to be in this group, you are in the sudoers-group and always able to do anything, it just requires to enter the password.

Comment: yeah, but this way I can do some of this stuff right from the IDEs.  I usually keep all the libraries  under `~` but while upgrading UBUNTU , it took the liberty of installing all sort of stuff  in the default locations. Now I run into these  surprise conflicts from time to time.  Have removed myself from the group to be on the safe side, though .

Comment: I don't get it; "the ability to modify /usr/local is effectively equivalent to root access" yet any file inside `/var/local` supposedly has this ability?

Comment: @Rolf: _users_  have "abilities", not files. That sentence can be read as: "the ability to modify `/usr/local` grants a user belonging to the `staff` group powers effectively equivalent to root"