# User account in sysadm group even though it isn't

Tags: server, sudo, groups

## TL;DR

I log in to a server `testserver` with my account `testuser` and I am able to perform a `sudo -s` because I am in the `sysadm` group.

When I query groups I get the `sysadm` group, but when I query the group directly with `cat /etc/group` or `getent group sysadm` my login is not listed in that group.

Why?

## Long version

I have a user account `testuser` that I can use to login via putty (SSH) to a terminal session on a server (Ubuntu 14.04) called `testserver`.

When I run the `groups` command I get the following output for my account:

```
sysadm
```

Ok, so I should be in the sysadm group. I then list the sysadm group members:

```
getent group sysadm
```

...which produces the following result:

```
sysadm:x:800:
```

At this point I am slightly confused. I (testuser) am in the group and again I'm (visually) not in that group, because there are no entries at the end of the groups output.

I took a look at the sudoer configuration with visudo. I have the following configuration:

```
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
#%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL
%sysadm ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
#%sudo  ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

That's all there is in that file.

## Summary

1. I have found out that I am in the `sysadm` group
2. The `sysadm` group does not contain any members
3. I can `sudo -s` and then do whatever I want to

## Questions

1. How can I retrieve information from the system which will tell me why I am in the **sysadm** group?
2. Are there any other configuration settings that will put my login in a group, that I am currently not aware of?
   a) Active Directory
   b) Policies
   c) ...

I have read the following articles so far, but none of them helped me find out why I am in the sysadm group but (visually) not in that group.

- [How can I view what groups a user is in?](https://askubuntu.com/q/856365/306457)
- [Implications of manually adding a user to the staff group](https://askubuntu.com/q/834075/306457)
- [How do I list the members of a group?](https://askubuntu.com/q/136788/306457)
- [Understanding Group Permissions](https://askubuntu.com/q/638326/306457)
- [Change in sudoers does not take effect. Ubuntu 16.10 fresh install + one line.](https://askubuntu.com/q/887009/306457)
- [General posts containing "group members" (askUbuntu Search)](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=group+members)

Comment: Does your entry in `/etc/passwd` put you in group 800 at login? `getent passwd $USER | cut -d: -f4` will show you your login group. How did you (or whoever) create the `testuser` account?

Comment: Your command returned a wonderful `800` back. So your comment is the answer to my question. This means that there is a default group for each user and this happens to be in my case the groupid of the `sysadm` group. Could you please post as response so that I can mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your entry in /etc/passwd put you in group 800 at login? `getent passwd $USER | cut -d: -f4` will show you your login group. How did you (or whoever) create the testuser account?

To change your `group`, you will have to change `/etc/passwd` (man `vipw`), AND change the group on all the files and directories with `sudo chgrp -R $NewGroup $HOME`, then log out and in again.

"User" (as opposed to "System") groups usually start at `1000`, but you can check in `/etc/login.defs` (`UID_MIN`).

Again, how did you (or whoever) create the `testuser` account?

Comment: The user was created for me (DBA) by the system administrator (root) and I have no knowledge how the user was created. I was just wondering how the link was made between my login account and the group. This is done during user creation.

Comment: Complain to the system administrator that she put you in a system group, and tell her she needs to read `man adduser`. Using `adduser`will prevent similar errors in the future.